# Change default font color for navigation-drawer and toolbar

Tags: vuetify.js

I would like to define the default font-color for the navigation-drawer and toolbar.

I looked at changing colors through theming: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme

Aswell as overriding scss defaults: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables

But nowhere can i find changing the needed setting.

Playground: codepen io/timar/pen/WNvxOYB

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vuetify CSS has multiple color classes for background as well as text. The format for the text color classes are in the format of: `.[color]--text`. There is also various flavoring for lighten, darken and accent in the format of: `.text--lighten-2`, for example. The naming of colors and such can be found at the [Vuetify Colors page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors).

What I have shown below, essentially forking the codepen in the OP, illustrates a method, `customColor`, to return a CSS class to set the text color based on the `item.title` value that is called on `v-list-item-title`.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        { title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard' },
        { title: 'Photos', icon: 'mdi-image' },
        { title: 'About', icon: 'mdi-help-box' },
      ],
      right: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    customColor(text) {
      return (text === 'Photos') ? 'green--text' : '';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      height="400"
      width="256"
      class="mx-auto"
    >
      <v-navigation-drawer permanent>
        <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title class="title">
              Application
            </v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-subtitle>
              subtext
            </v-list-item-subtitle>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
  
        <v-divider></v-divider>
  
        <v-list
          dense
          nav
        >
          <v-list-item
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.title"
            link
          >
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
  
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title
                :class="customColor(item.title)"
              >{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```